# How can i write anonymous method in my scenario

Tags: c#-2.0

Let me tell you all that i am not getting any type of error in my code it is working perfectly fine, I am here to know one specific thing about Anonymous method. So firstly it is my code. I have a class called Employee. in which there are three auto implemented properties and a function which is returning the employees names who git bonus salary, I am using delegates so there is no logic in this function and that is the reason this class and method is reusable.

```
class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public static void BonusForEmp(List<Employee> emp, Bonus Isavailable)
        {
            foreach (Employee e in emp)
            {
                if (Isavailable(e))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " got bonus");
                }
            }
        }

    }

     delegate bool Bonus(Employee Employes); // Delegate
```

Here It Is my Main method in which i create a list of employees and doing all the steps like creating a instance and passing the method as an argument.

```
List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "A", Salary = 12000});
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "B", Salary = 7999 });
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "C", Salary = 1999 });
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 4, Name = "D, Salary = 20000});
            Bonus B = new Bonus(BonusAvailabeFor); //instance of dlegate and pasing method name as an argument
            Employee.BonusForEmp(EmpList, B); //using 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

So All of you thinking that where is my method(BonusAvailableFor) in which i did all the logical work which matches the signature of delegate? Here it is

```
 public static bool BonusAvailabeFor(Employee eml) // the function with same signature of the delegate here we use our logic.
        {
            if (eml.Salary > 8000)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

So this code is working so perfectly nice and returning the names of employee whose Salary > 8000.
I just read anonymous method somewhere that is inline expression that can be used wherever a delegate type is expected.They provide us a way to create instance of delegate without having to write a separate method .. the definition looks great it will reduce my lines of code if i can implement this in my scenario, so how can i achieved it ? <=== (My Question)

Comment: you can also use LINQ for that:  `var BonusEarningEmployees= EmpList.Select( x => x.salary > 8000)` that should give you all the employees whose salary is greater than 8000.

Comment: @Achilles
i know that i can also use Findall() function here with list , but i am here to learn about anonymous method how can i write this code by implmenting anonymous method techinque <== this is my ques

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions

Comment: @Achilles can you write the code just as you write above about linq ? instead of links